# jquery ui accordion to selected headers

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, accordion

I have a complex structure of tags in my page.

```
<article>

       <h2>
       ...  
       </h2>

       <h2>
       ...  
       </h2>

       <h2>
       ...  
       </h2>

       <h2>
       ...  
       </h2>

       <h2>
       ...  
       </h2>

</article>
```

The page displays the lesson of a course, and h2 tags are titles of each section.
Inside each h2 tags, there are other jquery ui elements like tabs, accordions too, ...,

What I want is apply accordion jquery ui only to each h2 tag, because I have very much scroll....

I tried giving a class to all h2:

```
$(function() {
    $( ".accordion" ).accordion();
});
```

But it's not rendering well.

Comment: Normally what you'd do is `$("h2").accordion()`. How do you define *not rendering well*?

Answer (score 0):

You can make an accordion on whatever jQuery element, you are not forced to use class selector as in the example. So, what you means under *not rendering well*, which blgt already asked? At last, you can select desired elements by IDs and make accordion. For example:

```
$('#thisOne, #anotherOne').accordion();
```